# How can I force a page to re-render from within onSelectionChanged?

Tags: java, wicket

Several pages can show current and historical data/configuration. We want to allow the user to control the amount of historical data that is displayed. A setting for this is in the session; the setting will be added to a preferences page and the database. Our preferred method to make an on-the-fly adjustment is to use a `DropDownChoice` control on the base page.

I created model and entity classes within my BasePage class to handle these values.

```
private Integer setting;
private String description;
```

The code for the `DropDownChoice` control:

```
private TermSettingEntity tsetting;

private void buildCommon()
{
    // Number of prior terms to show
    tsetting = new TermSettingEntity(AlphPlusSession.get().getDateRange(), "dummy");
    TermSettingEntity[] toptions = new TermSettingEntity[] 
    {
            new TermSettingEntity(0, "Current Term"), 
            new TermSettingEntity(1, "One Prior Term"), 
            new TermSettingEntity(2, "Two Prior Terms"), 
            new TermSettingEntity(-1, "All Terms")
    };
    ChoiceRenderer<TermSettingModel> choiceRenderer = new ChoiceRenderer<TermSettingModel>("description", "setting");
    DropDownChoice<TermSettingModel> prefselect = new DropDownChoice<TermSettingModel>("termPref", 
            new PropertyModel<TermSettingModel>(this, "tsetting"), Arrays.asList(toptions), choiceRenderer)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public boolean isVisible()
        {
            // Show on the side panel
            return allowPreference;
        }

        protected boolean wantOnSelectionChangedNotifications()
        {
            return true;
        }

        protected void onSelectionChanged(final TermSettingModel newSelection)
        {
            System.out.format("onSelectionChanged(%s)%n", newSelection.getSetting().toString());
            AlphPlusSession.get().setDateRange(newSelection.getSetting());
            setResponsePage(getPage());
        }
    };
    prefselect.setNullValid(false);
    prefselect.setRequired(true);
    add(prefselect);
}
```

I changed a session value in `onSelectionChanged(..)`. The call to `setResponsePage(getPage())` causes the same response as clicking a page refresh: the tables are re-populated, with the same data, but the there is no data access to get more or less data.

Is there a method to force the entire `WebPage` to be re-issued, including re-fetching data from the database?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting the answers, please leave comments explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Would be great to have some details about the component which contains your historical data and how you create it.

Possibly the fastest code update:
Instead of `setResponsePage(getPage())`  you could use `setResponsePage(getPage().getClass())`
This forces a new page instance to be created (if your page needs PageParameters add them too).

Cleaner:
If not done yet, use models to set up your components.
Your components should update theirselves then. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Working+with+Wicket+models

Comment: Adding the `getClass()` call solves my immediate problem: the full page is re-constructed. The integration of this setting with the rest of the system (configuration page, database) has barely started. It was hard enough making the `DropDownChoice` work at all.

Answer (score 0):

After onSelectionChanged() your whole page will be rendered anyway, no need to fiddle with setResponsePage().

Your components are holding on stale data. As user5474918 has suggested, you should rework your code to use models correctly, e.g. instead of

```
new Label("id", foo.getBar())
```

... use a model indirection:

```
new Label("id", new PropertyModel(fooModel, "bar"))
```

PropertyModel is just one of several solutions to this.

Comment: The page may have called `ListView#populateItem(..)` but did not execute `List<EntityTermModel> pastList = termService.getListOfPastTerms(institionId, AlphPlusSession.get().getDateRange());` in the constructor. I am not clear how a` Label` applies to the `DropDownChoice` control.

Comment: A DropDownChoice works with models too, just call the right constructor:  https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/DropDownChoice.java#L159 This ensures that it always works on up-to-date data.

Comment: Mentioning models still mostly confuses me. Do I have to create a model, entity and renderer classes just to match an `Integer` value to (probably unilingual) display `String`s?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/compref/DropDownChoicePage.java